# Using ed22519 signature as entropy

Tags: encryption, signature, ed25519

I am developing an application in which all application state is entirely public. Each user of the application is equipped with their own ed22519 keypair, and the application can only ask users for signatures of arbitrary data.

I would like to store some private data for each user in the public application state. The private data for any given user should only be able to be decrypted by that specific user.

I believe the typical approach would be for the users to encrypt their own private data using their keypair and then the application would store that in the public application state. However, the application can only ask the users to sign data with their keypairs, not encrypt it.

Because of this, I was thinking of having the application ask the users to sign some message like `I am signing this message for <application> using <nonce>`, where  is a nonce that is stored publicly. This signature is then used as the random entropy to derive a new keypair, which can then be used to encrypt the private data.

Is this mechanism sound? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Can the user store one more keypair? If so, you can generate two keypairs, one for signatures and another for encryption. Sign the encryption public key using the signing key and send it to the application server. Then the server verifies the signature and uses the encryption public key to encrypt and store any payload.

Comment: Unfortunately the user cannot store any information

Comment: If all the states, including private keys, are public, what security guarantees can be expected? Furthermore, if the user never stores any private information, how can they be guaranteed exclusive rights to decrypt?

Comment: And if the ed25519 private keys can be stored correctly (private per user) why not use them as the input key material for a KDF?